# ER com relacionamento implícito

Tags: banco-de-dados, entidade-relacionamento

Estou fazendo um ER onde todas as tabelas tem que ter um "log" de quem fez um registro, ou seja, tenho uma tabela **usuário** que cria um **determinado registro** e no registro tem uma Foreign Key que indica o usuário que o criou. Minha dúvida é se posso deixar isso implícito ou se devo mostrar isso no diagrama?

Para ficar mais claro segue a imagem do que pretendo fazer que ao meu ver é algo implícito:

[image: Forma implícita]

Forma que esta atualmente que deixa explícito que um usuário esta relacionado a todas as tabelas:

[image: Forma explícita]

Se tiver outras abordagens para manter um "log" aceito sugestões.

Comment: Eu prefiro deixar explícito que os usuários também estarão nas tabelas de log, seguindo a sua estrutura atual. Para fins de documentação e para que outros desenvolvedores veja, isso claramente, facilitaria muito. E outra: uma vez que a foreign key existe nas tabelas, porque não demontrar isso claramente?

Comment: Rodrigo eu concordo com você nesses pontos que você mencionou, gostaria de saber se com um número grande de tabelas tem alguma abordagem diferente que eu posso usar ou que você recomendaria pra eu evitar relacionar a tabela usuário com as outras N tabelas?

Comment: Nesse caso eu gostaria também de saber a resposta. Gostaria que pessoas mais experientes pudessem responder, pois também "prevejo" uma certa "bagunça" no diagrama de outras 100 tabelas, por exemplo, também guardarem o usuário como FK. Estou curioso para ver as abordagens de quem já passou por isso!